# Is Puma WEB_CONCURRENCY on a per Dyno basis for Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma

I'm using Puma web server on Heroku, and currently have 3 of the standard 2x dynos. The app is Ruby on Rails.

My understanding is that by increasing `WEB_CONCURRENCY` in `/config/puma.rb` it increases the number of puma workers, at the expense of additional RAM usage.

**Current Setup:**

```
workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 5 }
```

**Question:**

Is the `5` concurrent workers on a per dyno basis, or overall?
If I have 3 dynos, does this mean I have 15 workers, or only 5?

I was previously looking for a way to check the current number of existing workers, but couldn't find any commands to do this on Heroku.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the web concurrency is on a per-dyno basis.
Each dyno is an independent container, running on a different server. So you should see each dyno as an independent server.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Heroku is awesome

Comment: @Damien Is there any formula to calculate the WEB_CONCURRENCY?. what will be the web concurrency, If I have 1 performance L dyno, What are all the factors to be consider for this one?